# Information regarding netstat output

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, security

On netstat, I see my port 22 in connection with 122.225.97.99. Does this mean someone is accessing ssh .. OR is it just something related to ubuntu

```
user@ubuntu:~$ netstat -ntu
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 100.72.4.xxx:22          122.225.97.99:14202     ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 100.72.4.xxx:22          122.225.97.99:3781      TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 100.72.4.xxx:22          122.225.97.99:8581      TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 100.72.4.xxx:22          122.225.97.99:5110      TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 100.72.4.xxx:22          122.225.97.99:49039     TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 100.72.4.xxx:22          122.225.97.99:53793     TIME_WAIT
tcp        0    432 100.72.4.xxx:22          202.88.235.123:54092    ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 100.72.4.xxx:22          202.88.235.123:54090    ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 100.72.4.xxx:22          122.225.97.99:56696     TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 100.72.4.xxx:59777       100.72.4.2:80           TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 100.72.4.xxx:22          122.225.97.99:55110     TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 100.72.4.xxx:22          122.225.97.99:10338     TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 100.72.4.xxx:22          202.88.235.123:53856    ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 100.72.4.xxx:22          122.225.97.99:2304      TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 100.72.4.xxx:22          122.225.97.99:16170     ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 100.72.4.xxx:22          122.225.97.99:14990     ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 100.72.4.xxx:22          122.225.97.99:9504      TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 100.72.4.xxx:22          122.225.97.99:47099     TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 100.72.4.xxx:22          122.225.97.99:47966     TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 100.72.4.xxx:59779       100.72.4.2:80           TIME_WAIT

General information and location of 122.225.97.99
IPv4 address:122.225.97.99
Reverse DNS:122.225.97.99
RIR:APNIC
Country:China 
RBL Status:Listed in CBL
Thread:No threats detected
```

Comment: It means someone is connecting to ssh repeatedly.  Look at your syslog (probably /var/log/auth.log).  If ssh is open to the internet, this is quite common.  Ensure you have good passwords set and root is not allowed to log in.  You can use fail2ban and a myriad of other tools to block them automatically.  You can also use iptables to limit access to networks you would expect ssh to originate from.

Comment: you are right! will do right away..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means someone is connecting to ssh repeatedly. Look at your syslog (probably /var/log/auth.log). If ssh is open to the internet, this is quite common. Ensure you have good passwords set and root is not allowed to log in. You can use fail2ban and a myriad of other tools to block them automatically. You can also use iptables to limit access to networks you would expect ssh to originate from.

Comment: To add to this you should change your default SSH port from 22 to something else. This will cut down on people trying to access it maliciously by a lot. You may also want to look into something like [fail2ban] (http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)